# An error occurring in starting hadoop in ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, ssh

I installed Hadoop == '3.3.4' in UBUNTU VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)".

After installation and formatting the namenode i worte the following command

`samar@pc:~/hadoop-3.3.4/sbin$ ./start-all.sh`

But it gave the output as:

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
Starting datanodes
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
Starting secondary namenodes [pc]
pc: ssh: connect to host pc port 22: Connection refused
2022-08-25 13:22:46,349 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

ssh connection output is:
[image]

Comment: Well, did you follow the instructions on adding a passwordless SSH key? Did you try to `ssh -vv localhost`? Can you show the output of that in an [edit]?

Comment: Is your machine actually running an SSH server? Maybe you need to `systemctl start sshd` first. Or, is port 22 open for SSH connections?

Comment: thanks buddy, I didn't knew that ssh-server is required XD

Comment: I believe on older versions of Ubuntu, it's running one by default. Technically, it's not needed. Only for the `start*.sh` scripts, but you can use `hadoop-daemon` commands directly instead

Comment: Please resolve my this issue too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73513383/an-error-while-running-an-apache-flume-agent